# Boot error after screwing up dual-boot files

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

Soooooo, I seem to have myself in a very particular situation. Let me start from the beginning, I set up dual boot with Windows 10, and Lubuntu. Everything went according to plan. I then decided that I wanted to remove dual-boot. I looked on several articles some saying to use bootrec.exe, to repair and remove it but then I realized "It doesn't use the windows boot manager... it uses grub." So with this knowledge I searched for guides on how to remove grub. I found a guide (http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/) I could not access my system drive, so I dual-booted into Lubuntu and used root to access the EFI folder and deleted the "ubuntu" folder and rebooted to a happy little message saying: Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key_ . I realize that all my data is still there. I realize that in deleting the "ubuntu" folder that I deleted critical files part of the loading of grub. I now need to somehow replace these files, and get back to Windows 10.

Sidenote: I don't have **bootrec.exe** as a command. I checked this before I deleted the grub files.

Thanks for the help,
-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to first reinstall GRUB using a **Live USB/CD** of Lubuntu and then repair your boot drive by using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Follow the steps on link provided and then use **bootrec.exe** to achieve your goal.

[You can follow these steps](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)

**Installing Boot-Repair**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

**Using Boot-Repair**

*Recommended repair*

launch Boot-Repair : type "boot-repair" in terminal.

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Comment: I don't have bootrec.exe as a command... it is not reconized as a command. Not only that but would Lububtu even have an option to reinstall grub? or should I just reunstall Lubuntu to its current partition, would that reinstall grub?

Comment: **bootrec.exe** would be the next step which is a function provided in Windows. First reinstall GRUB, by any means so atleat you will have a working PC and you can boot into Windows. Then follow the steps given in the provided link. 

P.S.: Go through provided link first.

Comment: Is there an option to reinstall GRUB using Lubuntu? I doubt there is. In that case **should I just reunstall Lubuntu to its current partition, would that reinstall grub?**

Comment: As provided in my answer go to Boot-Repair link and follow thoses steps.
You can aslo install GRUB through command line in Lubuntu

>sudo apt install grub-pc grub-pc-bin

Comment: When running the install command on a live usb of Lubuntu it says that it is already on the latest version, and doesn't do anything...

Comment: Thank you for your link to boot repair, I now have access to windows.

Comment: You  are requested to follow conventional way(one mentioned in forums and in the link provided) to remove Lubuntu from your system.