# Ubuntu 16.04 Crashed

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, crash

I have dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 on a windows laptop. I have been using it for a week now. All of a sudden while I was working on Ubuntu it just blacked out and when I tried switching back my laptop on it's going directly to Windows.

I did check the BIOS menu and it doesn't show any sign of Ubuntu there.

And furthermore, time setting on my Windows has been messed up too.

I don't know if this matters but my battery was in critical mode while I was working but it still had some charge left.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing which comes to my mind is performing a [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) operation. You can refer to [this answer]( https://askubuntu.com/a/990144/701605) for that.

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Thank you so much.  askubuntu.com/a/990144/701605 this helped me resolve my issue. All I had to do was download EasyUEFI software as mentioned in the link and move Ubuntu boot option up in the order.